# VBA macro working for ages, on other computers works well

Tags: excel, vba

Could you please help me to solve the problem with the macro that is processed too slow?
I tried to change the range to just 3 rows and it was processed 1 minute while on the other computers it lasts just 20s for over 300 rows. Is it caused by the Excel update and the dynamic arrays? If yes, do you know how to fix it?

```
Sub import_new_forecast()
Dim lrow, lcol, i, j, k As Long
Dim USED_WB As Workbook
Dim fcst_file As Variant
Dim data_arr(), ldata_arr(), colmap_arr(), fhead_arr(), head_arr()
Dim ans As Variant

fcst_file = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="XLS Files, *.xls", Title:="Provide RSM path", MultiSelect:=False)
Set USED_WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(fcst_file)
With USED_WB.ActiveSheet
    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Do Until CLng(.Cells(lrow, 2).Value) > 1 'Find last not empty row in RSM file
        lrow = lrow - 1
    Loop

    lcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    head_arr = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lcol)).Value
    data_arr = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrow, lcol)).Value
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Col_Map")
    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    colmap_arr() = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrow, 4))
End With

USED_WB.Close savechanges:=False

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast")
lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If lrow > 3 Then
        ans = MsgBox("Do you want to replace LForecast with current forecast?", vbYesNo)
        If ans = vbYes Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("L_Forecast").Cells.Clear
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast").Cells.Copy
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("L_Forecast").Cells(1, 1)
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            End With
        End If
    End If

    If lrow <= 4 Then lrow = 4
    Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(lrow, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
    fhead_arr = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lcol)).Value
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("L_Forecast")
    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ldata_arr = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrow, lcol)).Value
End With


ReDim final_arr(UBound(data_arr), UBound(fhead_arr, 2))
For i = 1 To UBound(final_arr)
    For j = 1 To UBound(final_arr, 2)
        If Not IsEmpty(colmap_arr(j, 3)) Then
            If IsNumeric(colmap_arr(j, 3)) Then
                If IsNumeric(data_arr(i, colmap_arr(j, 3))) Then
                    final_arr(i, j) = CDbl(data_arr(i, colmap_arr(j, 3)))
                Else
                    final_arr(i, j) = data_arr(i, colmap_arr(j, 3))
                End If
            ElseIf colmap_arr(j, 3) = "x" Then
                For k = 1 To UBound(ldata_arr)
                    If ldata_arr(k, 4) = final_arr(i, 4) Then
                        final_arr(i, j) = ldata_arr(k, j)
                    End If
                Next k
            ElseIf colmap_arr(j, 3) = "f" Then
                final_arr(i, j) = Replace(colmap_arr(j, 4), ";", ",")
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast")
    With .Cells(4, 1).Resize(UBound(final_arr), UBound(final_arr, 2))
        .Value = final_arr
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
End With

End Sub
End With
```

Comment: Did you try disabling calculation and screen updating while you set the values?

Comment: If you do that only once, disable and re-enable the calculations will not help too much, but if this piece of code is inside a loop it will help a lot, if there are (many) formulas in the workbook. Otherwise, putting the values of the array is something which must take less of a second... Why are you convinced that the problem is on this piece of code, especially on the line you name it being problematic... Is your full code so big to be posted?

Comment: I've already tried to disable calculation and the screen updating but it doesn't help. Code is quite long, I pointed the line `.Value = final_arr` because deleting it helps. Now you can see the whole code.

Comment: And there are no formulas in the workbook, just values.

Comment: Does `USED_WB` workbook have only one sheet? If  not, are you sure that `USED_WB.ActiveSheet` is the same sheet like on computers where you say that the code runs faster? Please try to compare what happens in your workbook with what is happening on the other computer inserting a row just above the `With...` you consider problematic: `Debug.Print UBound(final_arr, 1), UBound(final_arr, 2)`. And do the same on another 'faster' computer. If the returned values are the same, your computer must have a problem...

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the problem part of your code. Please note.

```
Sub import_new_forecast()
    'Dim lrow, lcol, i, j, k As Long '~~> vba requires you to format each variable on the same line
    Dim lrow As Long, lcol As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim USED_WB As Workbook
    Dim fcst_file As Variant
    Dim data_arr(), ldata_arr(), colmap_arr(), fhead_arr(), head_arr()
    Dim ans As Variant
    Dim Target As Range

    fcst_file = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="XLS Files, *.xls", Title:="Provide RSM path", MultiSelect:=False)

    Set USED_WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(fcst_file)

    With USED_WB.ActiveSheet
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' ~~> The line below doesn't make sense.

'        Do Until CLng(.Cells(lrow, 2).Value) > 1 'Find last not empty row in RSM file
'            lrow = lrow - 1
'        Loop

        lcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        head_arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lcol)).Value      '<~~ comma(.) added
        data_arr = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrow, lcol)).Value   '<~~ comma(.) added
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Col_Map")
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        colmap_arr() = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrow, 4)) '<~~ comma(.) added .Range
    End With

    USED_WB.Close savechanges:=False

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast")
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If lrow > 3 Then
                ans = MsgBox("Do you want to replace LForecast with current forecast?", vbYesNo)
                If ans = vbYes Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("L_Forecast").Cells.Clear
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast").Cells.Copy
                    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("L_Forecast").Cells(1, 1)
                        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    End With
                End If
            End If

        If lrow <= 4 Then lrow = 4
        'Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(lrow, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
        .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(lrow, 1)).EntireRow.Clear   '<~~ comma(.) added .Range
        fhead_arr = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lcol)).Value '<~~ comma(.) added .Range
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("L_Forecast")
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ldata_arr = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrow, lcol)).Value '<~~ comma(.) added .Range
    End With

    'ReDim final_arr( UBound(data_arr),  UBound(fhead_arr, 2))
    ReDim final_arr(1 To UBound(data_arr), 1 To UBound(fhead_arr, 2)) '<~~ dimesion index start at 1
    '~~~>  The way you define it is that the array starts at zero.

    For i = 1 To UBound(final_arr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(final_arr, 2)
            If Not IsEmpty(colmap_arr(j, 3)) Then
                If IsNumeric(colmap_arr(j, 3)) Then
                    If IsNumeric(data_arr(i, colmap_arr(j, 3))) Then
                        final_arr(i, j) = CDbl(data_arr(i, colmap_arr(j, 3)))
                    Else
                        final_arr(i, j) = data_arr(i, colmap_arr(j, 3))
                    End If
                ElseIf colmap_arr(j, 3) = "x" Then
                    For k = 1 To UBound(ldata_arr)
                        If ldata_arr(k, 4) = final_arr(i, 4) Then
                            final_arr(i, j) = ldata_arr(k, j)
                        End If
                    Next k
                ElseIf colmap_arr(j, 3) = "f" Then
                    final_arr(i, j) = Replace(colmap_arr(j, 4), ";", ",")
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast")
        With .Cells(4, 1).Resize(UBound(final_arr), UBound(final_arr, 2))
            .Value = final_arr
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```